# How do you relate one of several possible entities to another entity in Java EE with JPA?

Tags: jpa, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have the following JPA entities in my Java EE application:

- Person
- Company
- Asset

Each asset is owned by a person or a company so my first thought was to add properties to the asset that related it to Person or Company as shown below.

```
@Entity
public class Asset {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Person ownerP;
    @ManyToOne
    private Company ownerC;
    ...
}
```

I only want a single owner, so my second thought was that I could use inheritance to combine the two properties into one as shown below.

```
@Entity
public class Asset {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;
    ...
}
```

This leads me to the following question:

- What is the best way to model Owner?

In regular Java, I would create an Owner interface and Person and Company would implement Owner but my understanding is that this would not work with JPA.

What if I created the following inheritance hierarchy?

```
@Entity
public abstract class Owner {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class OwnerPerson extends Owner {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    private Person person;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class OwnerCompany extends Owner {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    private Company company;
    ...
}
```

I think this would work but would require me to create an Owner entity each time I created a Person or Company entity.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure it to be right. You should think that JPA really try describe same relationships as a database would do so think in terms of database Do you believe that there exists any table inheriting from another one? How would you express it?
In my opinion you have started to build the house from the roof instead of the basements. First of all, model it in your database and after that, use JPA to translate its relationships.

Comment: I am not following your logic.   Please provide an example of how you would model the described relationships so that a person or company could be the owner of the asset.

Comment: As I said, you must first model it in database and code in java after it. I believe that Person and Company look like if they were different tables with different attributes so Asset must have a relationship with Person and a relationship with Company. This means that Asset must contain an attribute that means "Person" and other that means "Company" and not a mixed one whose relationship would be ambiguous (JPA relationships must be fair and clear and a relationship between an asset and something that can be person or not wouldnt work)

Comment: Once explained it, if bot Company and Person share attributes, you can create a super class from which they both would extend inheriting these fields. Super class wouldn't have the "Entity" annotation because it wouldn't be an Entity, just a java class. Child classes would add their own explicit fields and these classes would have their own annotations defining the meaning of own and inherited fields

Comment: I think the super class will need to a JPA entity so that the JSF dataTable (actually PrimeFaces dataTable) will be able to display the complete list of owners which includes OwnerPerson and OwnerCompany objects. I will continue to explore the inheritance technique to see if it takes me where I want to be.   Thank you for your input.